# Use babel-polyfill inside phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, babeljs, polyfills, babel-polyfill

How can i use babel-polyfill inside phantomjs to get some es6 futures?

I have phantomjs 2.1.1, and babel-polyfill installed (via `npm install babel-polyfill`).

Here is file main.js:

```
require('babel-polyfill');
console.log(String.startsWith);
```

When i run `phantomjs main.js` it prints `undefined` to console, however babel-polyfill should add `String.startsWith` method.